# I want to enable Timer only when user is logged in

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to enable Timer only when user is logged in. How to go about this? I tried but getting session time out message even when user is on login screen.

```
#import "TIMERUIApplication.h"

@implementation TIMERUIApplication

//here we are listening for any touch. If the screen receives touch, the timer is reset
-(void)sendEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [super sendEvent:event];

    if (!myidleTimer)
    {
        [self resetIdleTimer];
    }

    NSSet *allTouches = [event allTouches];
    if ([allTouches count] > 0)
    {
        UITouchPhase phase = ((UITouch *)[allTouches anyObject]).phase;
        if (phase == UITouchPhaseBegan)
        {
            [self resetIdleTimer];
        }

    }
}

-(void)resetIdleTimer
{

    if (myidleTimer)
    {
        [myidleTimer invalidate];
    }
    //convert the wait period into minutes rather than seconds
    int timeout = kApplicationTimeoutInMinutes * 60;
    myidleTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:timeout target:self 
    selector:@selector(idleTimerExceeded) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];

}

    //if the timer reaches the limit as defined in kApplicationTimeoutInMinutes, post this notification
-(void)idleTimerExceeded {

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] 
    postNotificationName:kApplicationDidTimeoutNotification object:nil];

}
```

and

```
-(void)applicationDidTimeout:(NSNotification *) notif {

    NSLog (@"time exceeded!!");
    UIViewController *controller = [[UIStoryboard 
    storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:NULL] 
    instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"mainView"];

    //I've tried a few varieties of the if statement to no avail. Always goes to else.
    if ([controller isViewLoaded]) {

        NSLog(@"Already there!");
    }
    else {

        NSLog(@"go home");
        [(UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
        //[(TIMERUIApplication *)[UIApplication sharedApplication] resetIdleTimer];
    }
}
```

Comment: When you get the timeout message, check the "logged in" status, whatever that is and act accordingly.

Comment: when i open my app it showing alert for inactivity. I don't want that alert in my login page

Comment: Ok, but you need to write the code to not do anything if you are in the login screen; You need to track this state somewhere and check it in the timeout handler.  No-one else can tell you exactly what to do since you are writing the code.